# Why The Interval of f(x) is the same in Both One and Two Side Limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

My Question might be wired For some But It Will help me to get the idea of One Side Limits.

### My Book

Recall The Definition of One Side Limits :

- *Right Hand Limit*

if for every number ϵ>0 there is a number δ>0 such that

$$c<x<c+δ \quad\longrightarrow\quad \lvert f(x)- l\lvert<ϵ $$

- *Lift hand Limit*

if for every number ϵ>0 there is a number δ>0 such that
$$c-δ<x<c \quad\longrightarrow\quad \lvert f(x)- l\lvert<ϵ $$

### My Question

It Might Be weird to me That putting an Interval

$$\lvert f(x)- l\lvert<ϵ$$

in Either One of the definitions.

Consider Right hand limit, I'm assume that we need an interval such
$$l<f(x)<l+ϵ \quad$$

[image]

Because It's Impossible to get any value at $$c<x$$

and The same Thing for Left hand Side , we might put $$l-ϵ<f(x)<l \quad$$ instead of $$l-ϵ<f(x)<l+ϵ \quad$$ Since it's also impassible for $$c>x$$

[image]

What is the point of Use $$\lvert f(x)- l\lvert<ϵ $$ instead of what Just I  Wrote of intervals For set the interval of Epsilon?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if $f$ is decreasing?

Comment: Using $x>c$ does not necessarily imply $f(x) >l$. The right/left refers to values of $x$ with respect to $c$ and not to values of $f(x) $.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh- meaning there are cases we will have $$x>c$$ for $$|f(x)-l|<ϵ$$?!                                                                                                       
Could you give me an example for limit in this case where $$x>c$$ pointing to $$f(x)<l$$